# Limit alternating series

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Show that for any $b>0$ and $n>0$, the alternating sum of the series

$$
a_k=\prod_{i=1}^k\frac{1+b/(n+i)}{1+b/(n+1)}
$$

converges such that

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^k a_k \leq -\frac{1}{2}
$$

In fact

$$
a_k=a_{k-1}\frac{(n+k+b)(n+1)}{(n+k)(n+1+b)}
$$

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Have you tried the ratio test for proving convergence?

Comment: There are some indexing problems. Your sum starts with $k=0$, but definition of $a_k$ assumes that $k\geq 1$

Comment: I know the series converges. The issue is to find the limit of the sum.

Comment: The indexing in the summation is correct now. Thanks for the comment.